# why extra row in there in jquery data table

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using jquery data table version 1.10.There is an extra row showing inside the table.

[image]

how to hide/remove the second row?

Comment: Please add some relevant code that you used.

Comment: Not sure if that is actually a second row - it just looks like the headers height is increased to allow the name "DEPARTMENT NAME" to be displayed.

Comment: no,for header there is a separate table and in second table inside thead this extra row is showing.

Comment: @AnkitGupta - it is quite difficult to understand exactly what you are talking about - perhaps including some code instead of screenshots would be better.

Comment: There is a fix code structure,I can not show but I am using normal datatable options.This problem is in version 1.10, in previous version there is no such issue.

Comment: basically jquery is creating two tables,one table for header and another for data.In second table,there is a thead in which this row is present.